# params on my controllers is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a test in rspec that is not passing and I do not know the reason. The test accuses the following:

```
 1) SalesmenController POST #create redirect to new team
     Failure/Error: params.require(:salesmen).permit(:name, :company_id)

     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: salesmen
```

The test is:

```
    require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SalesmenController, type: :controller do
   include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

   before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:owner]
    @current_owner = FactoryGirl.create(:owner)
    sign_in @current_owner
    @current_company = FactoryGirl.create(:company, owner: @current_owner)
  end

  describe "POST #create" do
    before(:each) do
      salesman = create(:salesman, company: @current_company)
      post :create, params: {:company_id => @current_company.id, company: { name: salesman.name, company_id: @current_company.id } }
    end

    it "redirect to new team" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "Create team with right attributes" do
      expect(Salesman.last.company).to eql(@current_company)
      expect(Salesman.last.name).to eql(@salesman[:name])
    end
  end
end
```

My controller is:

```
def create
    @salesman = Salesman.new(params_salesman)
    authorize! :create, @salesman
    if @salesman.save
      redirect_to company_salesman_path
      flash[:notice] = "Salesman saved!"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Could not create salesman!"
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def params_salesman
    params.require(:salesman).permit(:name, :company_id)
  end
```

My routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :companies do
    resources :salesmen
    resources :goals do
      resources :days
    end
  end
  devise_for :owners, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
end
```

My factory is:

FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :salesman do
   name {FFaker::Name.name}
   company
 end
end

Anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Where is the code in the RSpec test file that actually creates the salesman object for your test?  Do you have a `before do` block or something where you have something like this  `@current_owner = FactoryGirl.create(:salesman)` or something?

Comment: I just edited with the rest of the test.

Comment: looks like you are missing `FactoryGirl` before the create method on that before block, shouldn't it be `salesman = FactoryGirl.create(:salesman, company: @current_company)`  Does that work?

Comment: Perhaps `params.require(:salesmen).permit(:name, :company_id)` should be `params.require(:salesman).permit(:name, :company_id)`?

Comment: @Rockwell Rice I try but don't work.

Comment: @villian i try with both, but don't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try `params.permit(:name, :company_id)` instead of `params.require(:salesman).permit(:name, :company_id)`. Reason being that in your test environment, you don't have `salesman` coming in your params.